# PHP - Wondering about efficiency of nested IF statements for user registration

Tags: php, validation, registration

I am working on a little project of designing a website for my friends and myself.
I am currently building the user registration system and am wondering if the way I am checking user's entries is the best it could be.

Um, ignore the api stuff, it is for eve and likely irrelevant.

I have plans for the `else`s.

Essentially, I would like to know if this is acceptable in terms of... everything.
And if not, what could I do to improve this.

I am newer to PHP, please be kind :)

So, this is what I am currently using:

```
if (!empty($_POST['username'])
&& !empty($_POST['password1'])
&& !empty($_POST['password2'])
&& !empty($_POST['email1'])
&& !empty($_POST['email2'])
&& !empty($_POST['keyID'])
&& !empty($_POST['vCode'])
){
 $api = new EVEAPI();
 if ($api->getCharacterID($_POST['username']) != 0){

     //The username is valid.

     if ($_POST['password1'] == $_POST['password2']){

         //Passwords match.

         if ($_POST['email1'] == $_POST['email2']
             && filter_var($_POST['email1'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)
             ){

             //Emails match and are in valid format.

             if ($api->isValidAPI($_POST['keyID'], $_POST['vCode'])){

                 //If the API returns something that is not an error, continue.

                 $xml = $api->getAPIKeyInfo($_POST['keyID'], $_POST['vCode']);
                 if ($xml->result->key->attributes()->type == 'Account'){

                     //If the 'type' of the returned API info is 'Account', continue.

                     foreach ($xml->result->key->rowset->row as $apiRow){
                         $charID = (int) $apiRow->attributes()->characterID;
                         if ($charID == $api->getCharacterID($_POST['username'])){

                             //DO SOMETHING WITH INFO

                         }
                         else{
                         }
                     }
                 }
                 else{
                 }
             }
             else{
             }
         }
         else{
         }
     }
     else{
     }
 }
 else{
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Efficiency wise this isn't going to matter all that much, but for maintainability's sake it will.

Instead of nesting so many ifs like that, try early failure with your ifs.  Something like this:

```
if ($api->getCharacterID($_POST['username']) == 0) {
    // Fail early.  Throw an exception, die, or whatever
}

// Continue along as normal, not in an else.

if ($_POST['email1'] != $_POST['email2']) {
    // Fail early.  Throw an exception, die, or whatever
}

// Etc.
```

That sort of strategy will generally serve you well unless there's a very good reason to not use it.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to read and not very clean. The way I do it is use negative if statements. By that I mean the following:

```
if ($api->getCharacterID($_POST['username']) == 0){
    // Username is not valid, so stop execution
}

if ($_POST['password1'] != $_POST['password2']) {
    // Send error to user and stop execution
}

// ...etc.
```

Now how do you stop execution? Well you have few options

1. Throw an exception
2. Use die statement
3. have a parameter that you change everytime you enter an if block, then check if you should continue.
4. some other solution

But the point is, this approache makes your code cleaner.

Cheers.

Comment: Hmm, so I could do the same thing with each `else`, so essentially it is just saving space?

Comment: I do not think it is about saving space, As Telgin explained in his answer, it is about maintaining your code and easier readability. What if you have 25 conditions to check? This will be a very hard to read code. Moreover, if you decide for some reason to change the order your conditions are executed, that will be hard to fix as well. It is easer to keep it that way.

Answer (score 0):

These days mostly programmer use jquery / Javascript for forms validations, but if you are using pure PHP the try below code, hope it will be good and secure obviously :)

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']);
  if($username == "")
  {
    $username_required = '<div>Please enter your username</div>';
    } else {
    $username_ok = true;
  }
```

Comment: I have a JS validation system, but the PHP validation is for security issues.

Comment: You need validation on server side, client sided validation can be easily bypassed.

Comment: yes PHP validation is very hard to bypass, so use my code as i used validation :)

Answer (score 0):

Typically in most validation patterns out there they have this errors array where you check for all the conditions and add error messages into the array if the array is empty at the end it only means that there are no errors..

For me i wouldn't want my code to look too nested like this i would use variables to dictate each step.

From there you can decide whether to display just the first error. It doesnt hurt to validate through everything at once because the processing should not be that extensive unless you have like 5000 form fields. I think it's ok.

When you code you must remember because code is written for humans and you will want to be kind to your eyes or for those who read your code.. Basically nested is ok. it saves some further processing and it also depends on the logic you need.

Yes its good to save time but at times you do things too nicely to minimize processing you have to weigh the needs if you do it so nice but in the end the time you save is so substantial then it makes no point.. The compiler is not going to pat your back and say good job anyways..

```
$errors = array();

$usernameValid = $api->getCharacterID($_POST['username']) != 0;
if (!$usernameValid) $errors[] = 'Username is not valid';
//If you want to store which attribute caused the error you can use the attribute name as array key
//if (!$usernameValid) $errors['username'] = 'Username is not valid';

$passwordMatches = $_POST['password1'] == $_POST['password2'];
if (!$passwordMatches) $errors[] = 'Password does not match';

if ($usernameValid && $passwordMatches)
{
  //What to do if user name and password passes validation. wooo hoo~
}

//Etc etc..
```